# How to log out of WooCommerce without confirming?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, logout

We want the users of a website to close the session without having to confirm it.

Currently, when we press the "Log Out" button, the user is directed to the URL htt://myWebSite.com/my-account/customer-logout/ and we must press "Confirm and Exit"

Well, we want to avoid this step and automatically log out when the user clicks the Logout Button

There is some plugin that could do this, but we prefer to use functions. We've tried things, but we can't get it right to get it done

```
add_action('wp_logout','ps_redirect_after_logout');
function ps_redirect_after_logout(){
         wp_redirect( 'https://miPaginaFavorita.com' );
         exit();
}
```

Another option that we have handled is the following, but it does not work either

```
add_action('check_admin_referer', 'logout_without_confirm', 10, 2);

   function logout_without_confirm($action, $result)

      {

      /**

      * Allow log out without confirmation

      */

      if ($action == "log-out" && !isset($_GET['_wpnonce'])) {

      $redirect_to = isset($_REQUEST['redirect_to']) ?
 function logout_without_confirm($action, $result)

      {

      /**

      * Allow log out without confirmation

      */

      if ($action == "log-out" && !isset($_GET['_wpnonce'])) {

      $redirect_to = isset($_REQUEST['redirect_to']) ?

      $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] : '';

      $location = str_replace('&amp;', '&', wp_logout_url($redirect_to));;

      header("Location: $location");

      die();

    }}
```

How can I modify my function to avoid confirming when logging out?
Thanks

Comment: Is your wordpress site miSiTioWeb.com or is that some kind of SSO provider?

Comment: that's just an example `url` that i put here in example mode. As you well know when we try to log out, it takes us to that page: `/my-account/customer-logout/`
Just that. My site is a normal WordPress site.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you most change url function in your button . check your theme file how create button for logout .
use 'wp_logout_url' function for skip Confirm page .
in my theme like this :

```
if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {
    $logout_link = wc_get_endpoint_url( 'customer-logout', '', wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) );
}
$logout_btn = '<a class="login" href="' . esc_url( $logout_link ) . '">Logout</a>';
```

For example, I did this to skip the page confirmation and work fine :

```
$logout_link = wp_logout_url( get_home_url() );
$logout_btn = '<a class="login" href="' . esc_url( $logout_link ) . '">Logout</a>';
```

I hope it helped you.

**Edit** --

**METHOD 2 :**

simple way => if you are redirect to "/customer-logout" when click logout button you can check and logout user with this function .
add code in your functions.php (is in your theme folder or child theme folder) .

```
function skip_logout_confirmation() {
global $wp;
if ( isset( $wp->query_vars['customer-logout'] ) ) {
    wp_redirect( str_replace( '&amp;', '&', wp_logout_url( home_url() ) ) );
    exit;
  }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'skip_logout_confirmation' );
```

Comment: Thank you. Please excuse me, I've tried to use your method, but I can't figure out how to do it. I can't find a way to add your function to my code. Should I find the class that has my logout button? In your case the class is `( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' )` ?  Should I change the WOOCOMMERCE class according to my theme? I got a little lost. I don't understand how to organize your example for me. Can you give me some detailed explanation so I can understand it? Imagine that you are talking to a person with little knowledge Thank you for your time

Comment: I apologize for my poor grammar. Pay attention, you must first check how the your logout button is made? . You must change the link of the logout button. You need to make changes in your theme file.
But there is another simpler method that you can use. I edited my previous answer, look at it again. enjoy and good luck .

Comment: In the case of the previous solution, the structure is different according to your theme.
You do not need to find and change this line ' ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ' . this only check woocmmerce is enable or not . It was specifically for my theme format .My suggestion is the second method that I introduced to you because it is easier for you.

Comment: I apologize for spending a long time responding. I perfectly understood your idea. With the second method that you have suggested, it has been easy and we get what we needed. I just have one problem that I forgot to mention. How can I direct the user to the page that I want when closing the session? 2- We are looking for a function to direct the user when they log in to a certain page according to the user role. Will it be compatible with the function that you have given me? Thank you for your effort to help me

Comment: your welcome . YES , you can put your url of the page you want into wp_logout_url function . for example i use home_url() you can change what you want . I did not clearly understand your next question about "direct the user according to role " . Can you give an example?

Comment: I had a function to direct users according to their role (admin, Customer, etc) to a certain page of the site, but when I added your function, my code does not work, and the user is directed to the URL of your code. `function my_custom_login_redirect($redirect_to, $request, $user) {
  global $user;
  if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
    if ( in_array( 'subscriber', $user->roles ) ) {
      return home_url("especias-ecologicas");
    } }
  return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_custom_login_redirect', 10, 3 );`

Comment: replace  skip_logout_confirmation function . i added check user role in function for you .   `function skip_logout_confirmation() { global $wp; if ( isset( $wp->query_vars['customer-logout'] ) ) { $redirect_to = home_url(); global $user; if (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) { // check role and change redirect url if (in_array('subscriber', $user->roles)) { $redirect_to = home_url("especias-ecologicas"); } } wp_redirect( str_replace( '&amp;', '&', wp_logout_url( $redirect_to ) ) ); exit; } } `

Comment: Thank you. this code doesn't work. I will keep the function of method number 2 of your answer. I will look for a solution to the problem of directing users to a certain page, according to the role they have. Don't worry, I'll ask another question later to try to correct this. You have been very kind dedicating your time to me. I am very grateful. I want to learn php and I can't find the right way. All the best